# Can I shard Mongo base on IP address?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Instead of sharding base on the data, can I shard based on where the request (IP address) coming from?

Hmmm one trick I think of is the data itself contains IP address.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to include an IP address field in each document and include it in your shard key.  Choosing a good shard key is quite a tricky thing to get right, it depends a lot on the shape of your data and how it'll be queried.

Here's a good place to start: [Choosing a Mongo Shard Key](http://tebros.com/2010/11/choosing-a-mongo-shard-key/)